# Visual Studio 2015 UI throws 'Invalid Argument' message on successful build

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Visual Studio 2015 throws the following dialog box when I successfully **build** the project – even if I do not run it:

[image: InvalidArgument=Value of '-2147483648' is not valid for 'RowPosition'.]

```
InvalidArgument=Value of '-2147483648' is not valid for 'RowPosition'.
```

It is connected to building process and to open WinForms designer and appears at the end of building phase, almost at the same moment with status line message "Rebuild all succeeded". If the project does NOT require recompilation (e.g. repeated run without any modification), or WinForms designer is not open, the message is not thrown.

**Is there some IDE log where I can find stack trace of such IDE errors?** (Or are there some other means to find and resolve this?)

I have seen this in releases *Update 1* and *Update 2*. This was never thrown in Visual Studio 2012.

Comment: With little to go on, `the error you're seeing is the result of trying to assign too large of a value to RowPosition`; you probably already know this. Are you doing any custom controls or anything?

Comment: @zaggler – yes, although they are not mine. I'll explore way you suggest, because if WinForms designer is closed, the error is not thrown. Perhaps some developer forgot something.

Comment: Seems like migration issues to VS  2015, try to compare the designer generated files.

Comment: @miroxlav a suggestion: search for `RowPosition` throughout the solution and comment out what you can and rebuild. This will help find out where the actual error is coming from.